# How to use different Spark version than as used in Cloudera's CDH cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I use Cloudera cluster with Apache Spark `2.1.0.cloudera1` installed, but I need a new class from the latest commit from Apache Spark git repository:

[BlockMatrix.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/BlockMatrix.scala)

I just copy-pasted the whole file to my sbt scala project but I don't know how to create sbt-assembly *MergeStrategy* to exclude the cluster provided class:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix
```

from

```
org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11/jars/spark-mllib_2.11-2.1.0.cloudera1.jar
```

and use the newly added project class.

My sbt.build file:

```
val sparkVersion = "2.1.0.cloudera1"

lazy val providedDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion
)

libraryDependencies ++= providedDependencies.map(_ % "provided")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Spark that does not correspond to the version as used in your environment just `sbt assembly` all the Spark dependencies in a single uber jar and `spark-submit` it.

Install [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and remove the line where you mark the Spark dependencies `provided` (which says to exclude them from `assembly` which is exactly the contrary to what we aim for).

```
libraryDependencies ++= providedDependencies.map(_ % "provided")
```

You have to use the proper version of Spark, i.e. the following line should be changed too (to reflect the version with `BlockMatrix.scala` in question).

```
val sparkVersion = "2.1.0.cloudera1"
```

You may want to use your locally-built Spark for this too. The point is to have all the dependencies in a single uber-jar which are supposed to override what's in your deployment environment.

Comment: OK thanks, but is it possible to copy only that one class (with original package) from the new library so I can avoid sending fat jar over ssh?

Comment: Don't think so. It *could* work but I'd consider it a coincidence.